# A question about “to becoming”

Tags: infinitives, gerunds, prepositional-phrases, ing

Would this sentence be correct?

> Being scared is the first step to becoming free.

The more I look at it, the less clear it becomes.

Comment: You're looking at two words that aren't a unit. "To becoming" is not a constituent by itself. _Becoming free_ is a gerund clause that functions as the object of the preposition _to_. What makes it look odd is that _to_ is also used as a marker for an infinitive clause, and _becoming_ isn't an infinitive. But _to_ doesn't mark the verb here -- it's not an infinitive complementizer; it's just a preposition and its object is _becoming free_. Moral: look for constituents, not for strings of words. Strings are mostly accidental.

Comment: Maybe this question is more suitable for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com). Or did you mean if the _meaning_ of the sentence is correct? In that case, I'd say hardly.

Comment: @MrLister: whether the meaning is correct is off-topic here; that's a philosophical question.

Comment: I've been around for a short while but I have seen several English Grammar questions be closed for being off-topic. For this reason I would say this one is off-topic too, so I've been led to believe. Unless there are double standards.

Comment: @Luis Of course there are. Everybody has their own standards; that is unavoidable.

Comment: Sorry if this was off-topic! This is the first time I have used this website, and I probably posted this question in haste, as I didn't look for other sections to post in. Thanks for the answers, especially John. I would be very interested in discussing the philosophical meaning behind this sentence, but as pointed out previously, that would definitely be off-topic. Interesting website! I'll look around some more.

Comment: @Lukeish: Don't worry about it. Nobody knows what "off-topic" means, because everybody has a different sense of what the "topic" is, or should be. Just like everybody has their own sense of what terms like _adjective, adverb,_ and _correct_ mean, among others. It's not easy to find information here.

Answer (score 2):

In an unsearchable and potentially ephemeral [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/183117/a-question-about-to-becoming#comment381147_183117) to the original posting, [Professor Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/15299/john-lawler) kindly presented the following answer: ¹

> You’re looking at two words that aren’t a unit. “To becoming” is not a constituent by itself.  *Becoming free* is a gerund clause that functions as the object of the preposition *to*.
>
> What makes it look odd is that *to* is also used as a marker for an infinitive clause, and *becoming* isn’t an infinitive. But *to* doesn’t mark the verb here — it’s not an infinitive complementizer; it’s just a preposition and its object is *becoming free*.
>
> Moral:  look for constituents, not for strings of words. Strings are mostly accidental.

I’ve marked this posting [Community Wiki](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) because it is John’s answer not my own, and so I deserve no reputation from it.

---

<sub>1. With paragraph breaks inserted for ease of reading where I thought they would most naturally fall. ―*tchrist*</sub>